# Authorization Header not working in Basic Authentication JAVA

Tags: java, http, basic-authentication

I am trying to make a program that connect to a server through basic authentication but when i try to set the "Authorization" HTTP header something go wrong because when I try to show the inserted headers there is no "Authorization" header in my HTTP-request, does anybody know why? 
This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Esse3Connection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String webPage = "http://192.168.1.1:80";
            String name = "admin";
            String password = "admin";

            String authString = name + ":" + password;
            System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
            String authEncBytes = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(authString.getBytes());
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
            System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);


            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
            urlConnection.connect();

            System.out.println(urlConnection.getRequestProperty("Authorization"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting:

```
        byte[] encoding = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(encoding);

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Comment: Already tried, that is not the problem, even if a write
`urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "hello");`
it still doesn't work